# DatagridView by SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns

[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvD94.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0j6R.png)

and I want to make a query in my database, so that it appears in my datagridview.

```
 public DataTable pesquisar(string produto)
        {
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

            string sqlQuery = "Select cd_produto, " +
                                  "ds_produto, " +
                                  "referencia, " +
                                  "ds_marca " +
                                  "FROM produto";

            command.CommandText = sqlQuery;

            
            try
            {
                command.Connection = conn.Conectar();

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, command.Connection))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (DataTable _DT = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(_DT);

                        return _DT;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I did it like this, but this way it adds new columns to my datagrid

Comment: Why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` and also calling `Fill`?

Comment: *"I have a datagrid"*. Do you, or do you actually have a `DataGridView`. Names are important because there are other controls that are named `DataGrid`. If you just always use the actual name of something then the chance of mistaking it for something else is significantly reduced.

Comment: The code you have posted has got nothing to do with any grid at all, so that code is not causing the issue you are referring to.

Comment: @jmcilhinney's answer is the correct answer, but an alternative answer is to return your SQL columns with the names expected using an alias. To do this, use the SQL `AS` keyword in your SELECT statement. Like so, `string sqlQuerry = "Select cd_produto, ds_produto AS [Descricão], referencia AS [Referencia], ds_marca AS [Marca] FROM produto";`.

Comment: @quaabaam, I assume you mean that, if you were to do that, you wouldn't actually add columns manually in the first place and the auto-generated columns would have the desired header text.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Why have you added tags for both MySQL and SQL Server? Based on your code, you're using SQL Server, so MySQL is completely irrelevant. The database is irrelevant anyway though. If your issue is with a `DataGridView` and you're binding a `DataTable` then how that `DataTable` was populated is irrelevant. There are tags for `DataGridView` and Windows Forms and they are relevant. I have made the appropriate edits. Now you just need to post the actually relevant code and exp0lanation, i.e. how you're creating those columns and how you're populating the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` and `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `true`, any columns/properties in the data source that do not match existing columns will have a new column generated for them. The way you match a column that you create to a column/property in the data source is to set the grid column's `DataPropertyName` property. For example, if you have a column in your data source named "cd_produto" then you need to set the `DataPropertyName` property of the corresponding grid column to "cd_produto" and then that source column will bind to that grid column.

Comment: with the alias I managed to solve it, but all this information helped me with more things I was trying to do hahah, thanks for everything